# Required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Hi I have this project running on Spring boot. When I tried to run, it give me the following error:

Description:

Field clientCredentialsApi in com.mycompany.microservice.myproject.bot.controller.BotCommandController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations' in your configuration.

Here is my Code:

```
Application.java

package com.mycompany.microservice.myproject
//some imports

@SpringBootApplication`
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.*")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And here is the Controller:

```
BotCommandController.java
package com.mycompany.microservice.myproject.bot.controller;
//some imports

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bot-command")
public class BotCommandController {

@Autowired
private RestOperations clientCredentialsApi;

@RequestMapping(value = "/sraix", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody String sraixCommand(@RequestParam(name = "input", required = false) final String input,@RequestParam(name = "cs", required = false) final String cs) throws Exception {

    final UserApiObject userApiObject = clientCredentialsApi.getForObject(env.getProperty("gms.location") + "/rest/user/" + userId, UserApiObject.class);

    return userApiObject.getRole();

}
```

Comment: what the code of your `RestOperations `? Try to add `@Service` or `@Component` on your class.Hope to help you.

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: you need to add the code for RestOperations

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autowire bean that you didn't define or implemented. `RestOperations` is an interface and has to be implemented.

```
@Autowired
private RestOperations clientCredentialsApi;
```

Spring is looking up for the classes annotated with @Bean or @Component or @Service to inject their references. In your case, you didn't define bean RestOperations and Spring can't inject it into BotCommandController.

Something like this:

```
@Bean
RestOperations rest(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
    return restTemplateBuilder.basicAuthorization("user", "password").build();
}
```

Comment: Do you have @Bean in the configuration similar to my example?

Comment: Dont have.. Actually its working on the other code. I just copy the code and put it in a microservice.

Comment: Try to search for classes that implement RestOperations in your application or methods that return it.